# JavaScript Dice Roll When Button Is Clicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple dice roller with Javascript that will display a random number between 1 and 6 when the button is clicked.

I have a button:

```
<button id="roll">Click to Roll</button>
```

With this script:

```
function diceRoll(min, max) {
    var min = Math.ceil(min);
    var max = Math.floor(max);
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    console.log(roll);
}

document.getElementById("roll").onclick = diceRoll(1, 6);
```

The random number will display when the page is first loaded, but when clicking the button nothing happens. How can I get this to work when the button is clicked, not when the page is loaded? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
document.getElementById("roll").onclick = function() {
    diceRoll(1, 6);
};
```

The issue with your current code is that when that line is run, `diceRoll(1, 6)` is executed, and then the result of calling that function is assigned to the `onclick` handler.

You need the `onclick` handler to instead be a function that can be called each time the button is clicked. So above I've created a new function that, when called, in turn calls `diceRoll(1, 6)`.

If it helps, this code is equivalent to what you're doing now (and hopefully reveals why that's wrong):

```
// Call diceRoll and store its result (which is undefined, since
// the function returns nothing).
var result = diceRoll(1, 6);

// Now take that result (undefined) and assign it to the button's
// onclick handler. This makes onclick undefined too.
document.getElementById("roll").onclick = result;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! It works now.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I see why it wasn't working now.